# Joint and conditional distributions of multiple variables

Tags: probability-distributions

If I have three random variables $X, Y$ and  $Z$ where $Y$ and $Z$ are independent. Is it true that $P(X,Y,Z)=P(X,Y)P(X,Z)$? What about $P(X\vert Y,Z)=P(X\vert Y)P(X\vert Z)$?

Answer (score 1):

No. Just consider $X$ independent from both $Y$ and $Z$, then

$$P(X,Y,Z) = P(X)P(Y)P(Z)$$
$$P(X,Y)P(X,Z) = P(X)^2P(Y)P(Z).$$

These are only equal if $X$ is constant.

For the second question, still considering independent $X$,

$$P(X|Y,Z) = P(X)$$
$$P(X|Y)P(X|Z) = P(X)^2,$$

which, as before, are only equal if $X$ is constant.

The inference that you can make from your assumptions is

$$P(X,Y,Z) = P(Y,Z)P(X|Y,Z) = P(Y)P(Z)P(X|Y,Z).$$

Comment: Hi Filipos, thanks for your answer. But what is it like if X is not independent to both Y and Z?

Comment: Consider $X = (Y, Z)$. We get $P(X)\delta_{X, (Y, Z)}$ versus $P(X)^2\delta_{X, (Y, Z)}$ in the first questions and $\delta_{X, (Y, Z)}$ versus $P(X)\delta_{X, (Y, Z)}$ in the second one.